# Morphisms whose reduction is projective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

IIUC Remark 5.3.5 in EGA II says that there exist proper non-projective morphisms $X\rightarrow Y$ where $Y$ is the spectrum of a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra such that the induced morphism $X_{red}\rightarrow Y_{red}$ is projective. Here is [.pdf](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1961__8__5_0.pdf#page=97) file.

May somebody give an example?

FWIW [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/dimension6.pdf) some examples of finite-dimensional commutative associative unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebras are listed.

Comment: Take a K3 surface and deform it at random over $\mathbf{C}[t]/(t^n)$. Deformation theory will tell you that for a very general choice no ample line bundle will deform.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger is this possible if we require the reduction to be smooth Fano variety or smooth rational variety?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Please confer Exercise III.5.9, p. 232, of Hartshorne's "Algebraic geometry".  It can happen that $X_{\text{red}}$ is even projective space.